# How to pass input with URL instead of passing ID via anchor tag URL

Tags: javascript, php

If user likes to change record he/she enters quantity and clicks on edit anchor tag to pass input with URL:

[image: ****]

```
<form action="saleentry-final.php" method="get" >
<?php 
    for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)  
    {
        if ($i == $total_results)
         {
         break;
         }
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"  name="check_list2[]" value="<?php echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'id');?>"/></td>
        <td><?php echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'item');?></td>
        <td><?php echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'batch_no');?></td>
        <td><?php echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'Mfg_date');?></td>
        <td><?php echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'Exp_date');?></td>
        <td><input name="movie[]" value="<?php echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'qty');?>" class="form-control"></td>
        <td><?php echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'rate');?></td>
        <td><?php echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'vat');?></td>
        <td><?php echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'price');?></td>
        <td><a href="saleentry-edit.php?id=<?php echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'id');?>">EDIT</a></td>
        <td><a href="salesentry-delete.php?id=<?php echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'id');?>">DELETE</a></td>
    </tr>  

    <?php $tot = $tot + mysql_result($result, $i, 'PRICE'); }  ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10">
            <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg  center-block" name="submit2">Create Invoice</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I am passing ID via anchor tag URL but how can I pass input with URL?

```
<a href="saleentry-edit.php?id=<?php echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'id');?>">EDIT</a>
```

I want to pass input value whatever user enter with URL to saleentry-edit.php page and in saleentry-edit.php page get id and user input value to  update quantity quickly and process dynamic then redirect to same page.

Comment: You can pass multiple values through url arguelments : your-page.php?id=<id_value>&var2=<val2>&var3=<val3>...

Comment: Note that `mysql_result()` has been deprecated since 20th of June 2013 and hasn't been supported since 21 July 2016.

Comment: thanks Dexter0015 ... i get the solution

Answer (score 0):

inside $i for loop `< input id="state<?php echo $i;?>" name="movie[]" value="<?php $sta = mysql_result($result, $i, 'qty');  echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'qty');?>" class="form-control">`

```
<input type="button" name="inspecionar" id="inspecionar" value="inspecionar" onclick="location.href='/Inventry-System/saleentry-edit.php?id=<?php echo mysql_result($result, $i, 'id');?>&quantity='+ document.getElementById('state<?php echo $i;?>').value;">
```